# How to declare routes with resources in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have some routes in routes.php in laravel

```
 // Code for rounting admin panel
 Route::resource('/admin','Admin\LoginController@index');
 Route::resource('/admin/dashboard','Admin\AdminController@index');
 Route::resource('/admin/movies','Admin\MovieController@index');
```

Now when I access url http://localhost/askspidy/admin I want to show login page and it works, but when i access url http://localhost/askspidy/admin/dashboard   it should go to dashboard but it's showing me login page only. 
I know this is because when it found /admin in any url it's bydefault goes to the route

```
 Route::resource('/admin','Admin\LoginController@index');
```

I know it's assuming that (/admin) is route to controller and (/dashboard) is the function declared in the controller but I want routing like this only so is there any other solution for this problem.

Comment: Try using namespace and prefix in your routes, to prevent repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [RESTful Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) takes over the responsibility of each action. You only need to list the name and the controller:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

If you wanted to only use the `index` method, you’d list it like this:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController', ['only' => [
    'index'
]]);
```

However, it looks like two of your routes are not suitable for resources (login and dashboard), as they should relate to editing a model.

You should instead just use a `get()` resource instead.

[From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#basic-controllers):

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

So in your case, it would be:

```
Route::get('/admin','Admin\LoginController@index');
Route::get('/admin/dashboard','Admin\AdminController@index');
Route::resource('/admin/movie','Admin\MovieController');
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, yes there was no need of resource for login & dashboard.